# How to replace character with a space found in the mid of the line but not at the second last position of the line

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

It's like
India/Delhi  S/V should get replaced as India Delhi SV

Comment: So you want the first occurrence to be replaced with a space, if it's in the middle of the line. If it's in the second to last position of the line, just remove it. What if the first occurrence is in the second to last position? Will there always be two '/'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your format stays the same... meaning there are only two instances of `/`

```
declare @var varchar(64) = 'India/Delhi S/V'

select replace(stuff(@var,charindex('/',@var,0),1,' '),'/','')
```

Comment: Too fast for me

Comment: Just this once @JohnCappelletti and it likely won't happen again lol

Comment: This is really clever.

Comment: Perhaps the second last position is not fixed.. And it can be third last character then also the above code will work like it can be India/Delhi migrates to A/C/C to be India Delhi migrates to ACC

Comment: this doesn't used fixed positions. Regarding the extra `/` at the end, just add another replace: `replace(replace(stuff(@var,charindex('/',@var,0),1,' '),'/',''),'/','')`